# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of undefined

Tags: javascript

Tenho um form que só vai dar submit caso a senha tenha somente letras e números, e após essa verificacao, deve redirecionar para um link. Codigo do form:

```
<form onsubmit="return Redirect(err, resp, body, password);">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="password-text" for="password">Senha</label><br>
    <input id="password" type="password" placeholder="Insira a senha" name="password" title = "Precisa contar no máximo 6 caracteres entre letras e números." required >
  </div>
  <button type="submit" class="form-button"">Acessar</button>
</form>
```

Código do JS:

```
var request = require('request');
var psw = /^[a-zA-Z0-9-]\w{1,6}$/;
request.get('Link X', function Redirect(err, resp, body, password){
  if(password.value.match(psw)){
    alert('Senha válida, redirecionando ..');
    document.location.assign(body);
    return false;
  }
  else{
    alert('Senha inválida. Tente novamente.');
    return true
  }
});
```

Para deixar mais claro, o 'Link X', possui somente um link no seu `<body>`, que é o link que eu quero redirecionar, então eu verifico o password digitado para ver se bate com os filtros, e após isso vou redirecionar para o 'body' que possui o link. Porem estou recebendo erro no meu 'if': 'Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of undefined'. Alguem tem alguma ideia ?

Comment: Matheus, e se você pegar o que foi digitado inserindo após o "```var psw....``` isso: ```var password = document.getElementById('password').value;``` . Será que a variável "password" não está sendo reconhecida?

Comment: Na função `function Redirect(err, resp, body, password)` você está esperando um password de retorno mas que no caso não está chegando. O ideal é checar todo o retorno da requisição.

Comment: O que retorna no parâmetro `password` da função? Coloque um `console.log(password)` antes do `if` para verificar.

Comment: @RodrigoTognin tentei assim tambem e deu o mesmo erro

Comment: @Sam como eu verifico no console.log o password se eu tenho que digitar ele no form ? Desculpa, so iniciante com javascript

Comment: Esse `request.get` é de onde? Algum framework?

Comment: Matheus, eu errei um detalhe... veja isso, por favor: ```var password = document.getElementById('password');``` Eu estava pegando o valor, na verdade era apenas para pegar o objeto já que o ```if``` acessa o valor

Comment: @Sam sim. (https://www.npmjs.com/package/request)

Comment: @RodrigoTognin Entao, aparentemente o erro do value foi corrigido, porem o javascript nao funciona mais, ele nao ta verificando o password nem redirecionando

Comment: @RodrigoTognin minto, o erro persiste, estava tentando de vários jeitos q acabei confundindo os códigos

Comment: @MatheusRondow Se você atribuir uma função no form em vez de colocar essa que está, assim: ```<form onsubmit="return VerifPass();">``` e daí no seu JS você cria essa função colocando todo esse código dentro dela: ```function VerifPass(){ ... <código> ... };```. Nesse caso, no retorno dela sendo ```false```, o "onsubmit" não ativaria..

Comment: @RodrigoTognin entao, é que eu nao consigo testar nada enquanto o erro do value continuar, talvez eu nao esteja pegando o password digitado, mas eu nao sei como verificar isso tambem

Comment: Então Matheus, o código que eu coloquei é exatamente para pegar o valor digitado. Uma vez que você coloca o "getElementById" que eu sugeri, você pega o que foi digitado no campo. Assim: ```var psw = document.getElementById('password');``` Isso faz com que a variável "psw" seja o objeto do campo da tela. Para acessar seu valor, você pode usar ```console.log(psw.value);```